# How to add json data into select tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have json data as below

```
{ "aaData": [["2","MAC"],["3","Apple"],["5","Windows"],["5","Unix"],["6","Linux"]]}
```

And I try with below jquery code but data not add with select tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mc_category").change(function() {
            $.getJSON("/admin/getSubCategory.php", null, function(data) {
            $("#subcategory").fillSelect(data);
        });
    });

 $.fn.fillSelect = function(data) {
    return this.clearSelect().each(function() {
        if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            var dropdownList = this;
            $.each(data, function(index, optionData) {
            var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    dropdownList.add(option);
                }
               else {
                    dropdownList.add(option, null);
               }
           });
     }
    });
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: updated subcategory is select tag

Comment: you probably just needed $("#subcategory").fillSelect(data.aaData);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just loop through the `aaData` array, and use the jQuery [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method to add each item to your `select` box.

I'm not sure what the `fillSelect` method does, but here's an implementation that you can replace it with:

```
var sel = $('#subcategory');
for (var i = 0; i < data.aaData.length; i++)
{
    var e = data.aaData[i];
    $('<option>').text(e[1]).val(e[0]).appendTo(sel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#subcategory").append(
     $.map(data.aaData,function(index,value){
          return $("<option/>").attr("value",value[0]).text(value[1]);
     }).get();
 );
```